# return filename after save in WebAPi

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I'm uploading a image using Web API.

```
public IHttpActionResult UploadImage()
{
     FileDescription filedescription = null;
    var allowedExt=new string[]{".png",".jpg",".jpeg"};
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
       Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();
       var imgTask = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider>(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {   
                MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = task.Result;
                var content = provider.Contents.ElementAt(0);
                Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                var receivedFileName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                var getExtension = Path.GetExtension(receivedFileName);                      
                if(allowedExt.Contains(getExtension.ToLower())){
                    string newFileName = "TheButler" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + getExtension;
                    var originalPath = Path.Combine("Folder Path Here", newFileName);
                    image.Save(originalPath);
                    var picture = new Images
                    {
                        ImagePath = newFileName
                    };
                    repos.ImagesRepo.Insert(picture);
                    repos.SaveChanges();
                    filedescription = new FileDescription(imagePath + newFileName, picture.Identifier); 
                }
        });

      if (filedescription == null)
       {
           return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { message="some error msg."}));
       }
       else
       {
           return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, filedescription));
       }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { message = "This request is not properly formatted" }));
    }
}
```

Above code I have used to save image, But every time `filedescription` even after image is successfully saved. What's wrong I'm doing here.

I want to return filedescription after image save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a lot of `async` methods in the wrong way. You should never make a call to an `async` method and then wait for it to finish in a synchronous manner (e.g. using `Wait()` or `Result`).

If an API exposes an `async` method, then `await` for it, turning also the calling method into an `async` method.

The reason why your `filedescription` variable is always null, is because you are checking it before you continuation has finished. This is truly a bad practice: if you need a value that is a result of an `async` operation, then you have to wait for it to finish, but in this case, using the `await` keyword.

This is the correct way of calling `async` methods and wait (asynchronously) for them to finish:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadImage()
{
    FileDescription filedescription = null;
    var allowedExt = new string[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        await Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
        var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());

        var content = provider.Contents.ElementAt(0);
        Stream stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        var receivedFileName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        var getExtension = Path.GetExtension(receivedFileName);
        if (allowedExt.Contains(getExtension.ToLower()))
        {
            string newFileName = "TheButler" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + getExtension;
            var originalPath = Path.Combine("Folder Path Here", newFileName);
            image.Save(originalPath);
            var picture = new Images
            {
                ImagePath = newFileName
            };
            repos.ImagesRepo.Insert(picture);
            repos.SaveChanges();
            filedescription = new FileDescription(imagePath + newFileName, picture.Identifier);
        }

        if (filedescription == null)
        {
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { message = "some error msg." }));
        }
        else
        {
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, filedescription));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { message = "This request is not properly formatted" }));
    }
}
```